# Ignore past values from FRP event stream

Tags: javascript, frp, bacon.js

I am using [BaconJS](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js/) to create two event streams likes this:

```
# Wait for start of the module
sStart = Bacon.fromCallback module.onStart.bind(module)
# Watch game ticks
sTick = Bacon.fromEventTarget emitter, 'tick'
# Combine it to do something
Bacon.onValues sStart, sTick, ->
    # Do something on each tick, but only when module has been started
```

I want to use it for synchronization. Once the module is started, it should start listening for ticks, not sooner. It almost works, but the callback is invoked for all past ticks that has been emitted before module start instead of just recent one. Than I want to that callback being invoked for each following tick.

I am pretty much starting with FRP, there is probably some elegant way how to deal with it, but I just don't see it for now. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're abusing [`Bacon.onValues`](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js#bacon-onvalues), whose purpose is to create a new stream.

If you want to wait for the start of the module, just register the listener only when it has started:

```
sTick = Bacon.fromEventTarget emitter, 'tick'

module.onStart ->
  # when module has been started
  sTick.onValue ->
    # Do something on each tick
```

For a completely FRP-style, you would use [`flatMap`](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js#observable-flatmap):

```
sStart = Bacon.fromCallback module.onStart.bind(module)
# Watch game ticks
sTick = Bacon.fromEventTarget emitter, 'tick'
# Combine it to a new stream that is made from sTicks by each sStart event
sTicksAfterStart = sStart.flatMap -> sTick
sTickeafterStart.onValue ->
  # Do something on each tick
```

Comment: Agreed, except for the suggested purpose of onValue method that doesn't create a new stream. Nor was onValue used in the original question.

Comment: Yeah, first solution is pretty much obvious, but since I am using that start event to synchronize with some other events, I thought it might be better to use stream for that too and I wanted to get ride of callback doom. Your solution with `flatMap` works great. Thanks.

Comment: @raimohanska I wasn't even using `onValue`, but `onValues` which should be shorthand to work like `Bacon.combineAsArray(...).onValues()`.

Comment: @raimohanska: Ah thanks, typo. There isn't even any `Bacon.onValue`…

Comment: @FredyC: You could also use `flatMapLatest` or the more promise-like `flatMapFirst`, they should work equally for a single `start` event.

Answer (score 3):

You can skip values using `skipUntil` like here.

```
startE = Bacon.fromCallback module.onStart.bind(module)
tickE = Bacon.fromEventTarget emitter, 'tick'
tickE.skipUntil(startE).onValue (tickValue) -> console.log tickValue
```

The `flatMap` solution above is valid too, but I find `skipUntil` easier to read.

Comment: This looks great too and maybe it's more readable than `flatMap`. Seems I should have waited longer with marking answer. I like this more.